# Laravel 4 and Blade, How to output blade variable in form label

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, laravel-blade

There is probably a really easy answer to this question. I need to make a Label based on a fixed string such as 'quesID' followed with a number stored in a variable.

So far I have this

```
 {{ Form::label($question->que_question_id, 'quesID') }}
```

Outputs

```
 <label for="2">quesID</label>
```

I have tried

```
  {{ Form::text($question->que_question_id, 'quesID' $question->que_question_id) }}
```

But I get syntax errors. Is there a way to output the varible?

Comment: how exactely do you want the output to be? you want to make a label or text area?

Comment: Sorry I meant for it to be both. Error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{ Form::text($question->que_question_id, 'quesID '.$question->que_question_id) }}
```